# Drawing neural networks

Tags: neural-network

Similar to the figures in [this](https://youtu.be/Ilg3gGewQ5U?t=11m57s) 3Blue1Brown video, I would like to create a basic figure of a multilayer perceptron (neural network).

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wrote an in-browser tool for this: [NN-SVG](http://alexlenail.me/NN-SVG/index.html). Choose from FCNN layout, LeNet layout, and AlexNet layout.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Grant Sanderson a.k.a. 3Blue1Brown writes his own code to produce the figures he presents in his videos. The code is available at https://github.com/3b1b/manim and you may find the code for the neural network figures in https://github.com/3b1b/manim/tree/master/old_projects/nn

Also: [How to draw Deep learning network architecture diagrams?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/14899/843)

Comment: `nn` has been moved to `old_projects`